# Using doube quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to echo some text that contains double quotation marks in a text file using PowerShell:

```
powershell echo " > file.txt
```

But this fails, I did my searching, and it suggested to use the ` character to escape quotes, but this did not work.

Comment: `' " ' > file.txt` or " `" " > file.txt

Comment: Is the double quote for the php or to be passed in for the powershell function?

Comment: I need to run this command from the windows command prompt like so (powershell echo " > file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You want to do do something like this as per the PowerShell quoting [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1):

Use single quote to define your string:

```
echo '"' > file.txt
```

Or use double quotes to define your string and escape your character with the ` character:

```
echo "`"" > file.txt
```

You could also use the Set-Content PowerShell command to create the file as well:

```
'"' | Set-Content file.txt
```

Comment: this (echo '"' > file.txt) and this (echo "`"" > file.txt) only echos to the command prompt and this ('"' | set-content file.txt) generates an empty text file only

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but it works fine for me and in a get a double quote only in the file.txt file.  Are you sure you are running the commands in a powershell prompt?

Comment: actually I need to run the command from a windows command prompt not from a powershell prompt, maybe that is the problem, how do I run this command from a powershell prompt ?

Comment: Run powershell from start menu or from in cod.exe should get you a powershell prompt.  Cmd.exe has weird rules around escaping quote chars, I’m not sure it can be done with the echo command.

Comment: it can be done using the echo command like so (echo ^" > file.txt) - however when I prefix the previous command with powershell it does not work